# php generate webcal

Tags: php, cakephp, icalendar, vcalendar

I am trying to get my script to generate an iCalendar, but mac calendar program keeps telling me the data is invalid.  I'm using cakephp.  Here's what I have -- any clues?:

```
function webcal() {
    Configure::write('debug', 0); 
    $this->autoRender = false; 
    echo header( 'Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8' );  
    ?>
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uid1@example.com
DTSTAMP:19970714T170000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=John Doe:MAILTO:john.doe@example.com
DTSTART:20110514T170000Z
DTEND:20110515T035959Z
SUMMARY:Bastille Day Party
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
    <?php
    exit(200);      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this in your controller? why not put it in a seperate "blank" layout instead of trying to hack the controller to do something it's not meant to do.

```
// controller code
function webcal(){
    Configure::write('debug', 0); 
    echo header( 'Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8' );  
    $this->layout = 'blank' // depending on what version of cakephp you're using this might be different
}

// layout code in /app/views/layout/blank.ctp
echo $content_for_layout;

// view code in /app/views/<controller>/webcal.ctp
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uid1@example.com
DTSTAMP:19970714T170000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=John Doe:MAILTO:john.doe@example.com
DTSTART:20110514T170000Z
DTEND:20110515T035959Z
SUMMARY:Bastille Day Party
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

don't forget to pass the view any variables you may need with `$this->set()`

Comment: This generated a bunch of code, not my calendar.  Did not work.

Comment: It generated a standard layout, but I fixed that by dropping the header line and using a router to route anything webcal.ics to the webcal function.  That sort of worked -- it gave me an ICS file that downloaded and could be added to my calendar.  But my calendar still won't let me subscribe to the same url.  I've been searching for what magic words need to be in the file to let me subscribe, but no luck.  I even am trying to use a sample of one that works.  But mac is being too helpful.  I can't download the file, only add it to my cal.  You're getting me close...

Comment: I figured out the problem:  It was redirecting for auth.  Once I fixed that, it worked.  Thanks!